# Which nameserver does awstats use?

Tags: dns, awstats, nameservers

I'm using awstats to produce statistics for my webservers. But sometimes I get unresolved IPs and I know that my nameserver knows those IP addresses. Is it possible to change the nameserver which awstats uses?

I hope you have a tip for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awstats would use recursive nameserver configured for a machine where you're running log analysis.

But resolution of IP addresses (called "reverse DNS") is something that often mistreated by IP-block owners.

If you think you can do better job resolving addresses you might disable AWStats DNS lookups and provide pre-processed logs, where IPs replaced to some kind of strings you generated...

I'm not user of AWStats, some info I found might be outdated:

- http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_faq.html#DNS
- see also example of program that does resolution, logresolvemerge